# How do I submit another pull request once the first one was merged?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked a public Github repository, cloned the fork to a local repo, made some changes, pushed them to the master branch of my fork. Then I opened a pull request and it was merged into the original repo.

Now I want to make next changes. I do them locally, push to the master branch of my fork and try to open another pull request. Github shows both the new changes and the previously merged changes as belonging to this new pull request. Clearly I only want the new changes listed.

What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right?

Comment: Have you tried rebasing your local branch off of the upstream master?

Comment: @ChrisHeald: Well, no, but in plain words what should I have done?

Comment: If the merging committer used merge method that didn't preserve the commit SHAs, then your branch can't necessarily do a clean merge. It may be easiest to fork off your current (modified) branch, reset master, `git pull origin master`, then cherry-pick in your new changeset. If the commit SHAs were preserved, then you could probably just `git rebase origin/master`, which will unwind your commits, update to the master, then replay your commits on top of that new head.

Comment: Since the repository is public, is it possible to get a link to your pull request so that we can also take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pushed them to the master branch of my fork

This can makes your next pull request hard to merge. What you should do now is

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

where `upstream` is the "original" repo, to get your `master` branch in line with its `master`. The `rebase` may take manual editing. Now, to submit a pull request, *branch* off master:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
# edit edit edit
git push origin new-branch
```

and submit a pull request from your new branch. This way, your `master` branch stays in sync with the original repo's.

If you still have commits in your `master` that are not in upstream's `master`, make sure you put those in a separate branch, then `git reset --hard` the `master` branch.