# How do I replay the changes from the origin repo into my fork on Github?

Tags: git, github

There's someone else's repo with a MIT-licensed project and I've forked it and submit pull requests once in a while and other contributors also push their changes in there, but the master branch of my fork doesn't have all those changes (I push into a new branch for every new pull request).

So I'd like to have all the changes from the original repo be replayed on the master branch of my fork. Will the following do the job?

```
 git checkout master
 git pull --rebase SomeoneElsesRepo master
 git push MyFork master
```

Will I be able to submit pull requests without the changes pulled by the `git pull` attributed to the pull request (as it was described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18053860/57428))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [Github Guide](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork) for this.

TL;DR:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/<otheruser>/<repo>.git
git fetch upstream
```

Option a) If you like merging:

```bsh
# assuming you're on master
git merge upstream/master
git push origin # assuming origin is your fork
```

Option b) If you'd rather rebase:

```bsh
# assuming you're on master
git rebase upstream/master
git push origin # this might fail with a 'non-fast-forward' error
    # in which case, insert --force after the word 'push'
```

---

Regarding the pull request (PR):

A PR will always contain all commits which are in your branch and which are not in the target branch. If you rebase/merge in commits which arent in your target branch? Yeap, they'll show up in the PR. Don't want that to happen? Rebase or cherry-pick only the commits you want in the PR into a new branch. (Srsly, there's a bazillion guides for this on Google and here on SO.)

Comment: When using `rebase` (vs. another local repo) I kept getting errors indicating that the remote branch was ambiguous or not a single revision. I fixed it by using `git show-ref` and then typing in the name (right hand column value) of the remote's branch that I wanted, as in `git rebase refs/remotes/<name of remote>/<branch name>`.