# How do I avoid typing the full Github repository URLs in each command?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have forked a public repository and want to pull the changes from the original one and then make my changes and then commit them to a new branch and push that branch to my fork. I follow the steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055060/57428)

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase https://github.com/OtherUser/OtherUserRepo master
git checkout -b new-branch
# edit edit edit
git push https://github.com/Me/MyRepo new-branch
```

and it looks like I have to type the URLs every time.

Is there a way to avoid typing them every time? Perhaps some shortcuts or something?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes - you need to set up a remote for the non-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this [Github Guide on *Syncing a fork*](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork) and a [whole category of guides](https://help.github.com/categories/18/articles) on working with remotes.

TL;DR:

```bsh
# get list of existing remotes in your repo
git remote -v
git remote add <remotename> <remoteurl>
```

Where `<remotename>` is any name that did not show up in the output of `git remote -v`. The name is arbitrary and only used as a local alias in your clone.